# W*-completion of a C*-algebra?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

tl;dr: Is there such a thing as a W*-completion of a C*-algebra, and if so, where can I read about it?

I'm wondering about the relationship between (abstract) C*-algebras and W*-algebras.  On the one hand, every W*-algebra is a C*-algebra.  On the other hand, it seems to me that it should be possible to complete any C*-algebra to a W*-algebra.  (Categorially, this would be a reflection.)  In the case of commutative algebras, I even think that I know how this works: every commutative C*-algebra is the algebra of continuous functions on some compact Hausdorff space, and we extend this to the W*-algebra of essentially bounded Borel-measurable functions on the space (considered up to equality almost everywhere). [Warning: this is determined in the comments to be wrong.]

So, is this correct?  Does it work for noncommutative algebras as well?  Is there a good algebro-analytic (without passing through topology) description of this?  Is there a good reference, especially online?

Also, in the commutative case, it seems that every state (positive normal linear functional) on a C*-algebra extends uniquely to its W*-completion, so they have the same space of states.  Is this correct?  Does it extend to the noncommutative case?

Another question is how this relates to concrete algebras (those given as algebras of operators on some Hilbert space).  One way to complete a C*-algebra would be to pick a concrete representation and take its weak closure (or double commutant).  But I expect that this will depend on the representation chosen.  (And my analysis is bad enough that I can't check this for even the commutative case.)

I'd appreciate any help even for the main question, never mind this stuff about states and representations!

Comment: Take the second dual (sorry for terseness, am in a bit of a rush) -- this is called the universal or enveloping W*-algebra of your original B*-algebra. (Yes, I believe in the distinction between B* and C*.) Note that in the commutative case this does not give what you guessed, I would have to think a bit more about what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: The embedding of A into its second dual then acts as the unit of your adjunction, I think

Comment: Last thing for now: your statement about states (in the commutative case) is incorrect. $l^\infty$ has, for those of us who worship The Great Satan that is AC, many more states than $c_0$ does - this is how one gets invariant means for instance.

Comment: I continued searching M.O after asking, and part of the answer is in question 60328, [What kind of completion is this?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60328/what-kind-of-completion-is-this).

*  The standard term for the W*-completion of a C*-algebra is "enveloping von Neumann algebra"; it may be constructed as the double dual.
*  In the commutative case, viewed as topology, the term is "hyperstonean cover"; viewed as analysis, I can read about it in Conway (which I own).

So I'm left with asking for confirmation and references to enveloping W*-algebras.

Comment: (I wrote my comment before Yemon's appeared, but thanks, Yemon!)

Comment: A short comment: there are some minimal and maximal representation for a $C^*$ algebra, if I remember correctly, and they coincide iff $C^*$ algebra  is nuclear...

Comment: commutative $C^*$ algebras are nuclear, btw.

Comment: If you start with a commutative W* algebra, regard it as a C* algebra and "complete" it in your way described above, you get a larger algebra and not the original one. Thus your completion for commutative algebras is not such a good idea.

Comment: Florian: but this is the nature of categorical "completions". The price paid for naturality is that usually one does not have minimality.

Comment: PM: nuclearity is to do with minimal and maximal tensor products coinciding. Are you thinking of group C*-algebras? if G is a discrete group and its reduced C*-algebra is nuclear, then the reduced and full C*-algebras coincide (since G is forced to be amenable, by a result of Lance)

Comment: @Yemon: OK, if you think of completion just as an adjoint functor to the embedding functor. I had examples of completion from analysis in mind, such as completion of a metric space, a normed space (to a Banach space) or a subset of a topological space (to its closure).

Comment: Small addendum, which I forgot to mention in the earlier comments: the same "embed into the double dual" functor also works just on the level of Banach spaces. That is, if we regard dual Banach spaces as a subcategory of Banach spaces, then the inclusion functor has a left adjoint, which sends a Banach space to its double dual. (I really must get back to writing things on the nLab...)

Comment: @Yemon Choi: I thought that nuclear $C^*$ algebras have only essentially on faithful representations, and that's what makes the tensor product unique, and the $C^*$ algebra of an amenable group being one example here, but I will be gladful, if you correct me... I am not working in$C^*$ algebras=)

Comment: Just to mention two other $C^*$ algebraic constructions which have to do with compactifications of a space, adjoining a unity is the one-point compactification, and the multiplier algebra is the Stone-Cech compactifications.

Comment: @ Florian: This is a fair point, showing that the term "completion" is not a good one.  Some reflections are idempotent, and these are the real [completions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/completion), but others are not.  I was hoping that this one might be, but clearly it's not in general, since W*-algebras aren't in general reflexive.

Comment: @ Yemon regarding states:  Somehow I've gotten the impression that the states on $C(X)$ and the states on $L^\infty(X)$ are in each case just the (Radon) probability measures on $X$.  (Thus the pure states for both would be the points of $X$, and it would follow that the hyperstonean cover of $X$ has the same points, just a different topology, which is possible but kind of weird.)  But apparently, this is just wrong about $L^\infty(X)$.

Comment: @Toby: if $X$ is, say, the unit interval with usual topology, and $L^\infty(X)$ is the bounded Lebesgue measurable functions on it (modulo almost everywhere caveats, yadda yadda) then "evaluation at $x$" is a (pure) state on $C(X)$ but isn't even well-defined on $L^\infty(X)$. The "nice" states on $L^\infty(X)$, i.e. those respecting the weak-star topology that it has as a $W*$-algebra, turn out to be given by "integration against $f$" for $f$ a positive integrable Lebesgue measurable function.

Comment: Thanks, Yemon, that makes it obvious.  Also, to make sure that I'm not hallucinating, $f$ should not just be integrable but in fact integrate to $1$, for integration against it to be a state.

Comment: As this ancient question has just been bumped: surely in the commutative case you simply want the bounded Borel functions?  If you say "essentially bounded" and "up to equality almost everywhere" you have to specify a measure, or at least a $\sigma$-ideal of null sets, and I don't see that there's a canonical choice.

Comment: @NateEldredge is that a vN algebra? Cf. Dixmier's old example: the algebra of bounded Baire functions modulo the obvious equivalence is not a vN algebra. (Hence why the canonical Wstar envelope of C(X) has to be the bidual of C(X), I think.)

Comment: @YemonChoi: That was a dumb comment, I'm way out of my depth here.  But let me ask a dumb question, then: say $X = [0,1]$.  If we're trying to "complete" $C([0,1])$, and the claim is we should get $L^\infty([0,1], m)$, why should $m$ be Lebesgue measure?  Why not some other measure?  Or does it somehow not matter?

Comment: @NateEldredge To me this is precisely why Toby's guess was incorrect, and $L^\infty([0,1],m)$ is **not** the canonical completion -- because it chooses Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Since we're talking about $L^\infty$, it doesn't actually choose a measure; as Nate's first comment notes, it's enough to choose the null sets.  But this is still too much information; it's not given by the continuous structure on $[0,1]$ (although it *is* given by the smooth structure).

Comment: I will risk bumping this question to reduce the net wrongness of statements on the internet. $L^\infty([0,1],\mu)$ is *not* the enveloping algebra of $C([0,1])$, but a proper quotient thereof. The predual of $C([0,1])^{**}$ is $C([0,1])^*$. Now, $\delta$-measures of points in $[0,1]$ form a norm-discrete subset of continuum cardinality in $C([0,1])^*$, so $C([0,1])^{**}$ does not have separable predual. But the predual of $L^\infty([0,1],\mu)$ is $L^1([0,1],\mu)$, which is norm-separable.

Comment: In some sense that can be made precise, $C(X)^{**}$ is a space that puts together $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ for all Borel measures $\mu$ on $[0,1]$. In a compatible way (*i.e.* $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ is always a quotient of $C(X)^{**}$).

Comment: @NateEldredge $\mathcal{L}^\infty(X)$ is not the enveloping von Neumann algebra on $X$, because it is not a von Neumann algebra, except in trivial cases -- if all singletons are Borel and there are non-Borel sets, then there is a bounded directed set with no supremum (taking the net to consist of $\chi_S$ where $S$ is a finite set of some non-Borel set). It is a kind of enveloping Rickart C$^*$-algebra, however, just as the Baire sets of a compact Hausdorff are the "free $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra" on it.

Comment: I should specify, that by $\mathcal{L}^\infty$ I mean bounded measurable functions, and by $L^\infty$ I mean (essentially) bounded measurable functions identified if they agree outside a null set.

Comment: @RobertFurber : Reviving this again after almost two years, if I were to try to make precise the claim in your second comment above, I would make a diagram in the category of $W^*$-algebras consisting of the algebras $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ and the quotient maps $L^\infty(X,\mu)\to L^\infty(X,\nu)$ whenever $\nu\ll\mu$, then take the inverse limit of this diagram. Does this get me $C(X)^{**}$?

Answer (score 13):

The universal enveloping W* algebra of a C* algebra is discussed in detail in chapter III.2 of volume 1 of Takesaki's work on "Theory of operator algebra". It is universal in the sense that any map to an W* algebra factors through it (modulo some mumbling about topologies), and as mentioned above is given by the double dual of the C* algebra. This is called the Sherman-Takeda theorem, and was announced by Sherman in 1950 and proved by Takeda in 1954.

Comment: Thanks, I can find that book at my university library, so I'll check it out!