# two concepts of positivity for elements of $C(X)$ when $X$ is hyper-stonean

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $X$ is a compact space. Let $M(X)=C(X)^*$ denote the Banach space of regular measures. Is the following statement true:

$F:M(X)\to\mathbb{C}$ is a positive functional if and only if the corresponding element in $C(\widetilde{X})$ is a positive function, where $\widetilde{X}$ denotes the hyper-stonean cover of $X$. (see for example [mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60328/what-kind-of-completion-is-this) for)