# Ultraweak topology in abelian von Neumann algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be an abelian von Neumann algebra acting on the (not necessarily separable) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (with identity $I$). From the Gelfand-Neumark theorem, there is a compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that $A \cong C(X)$, the $*$-algebra of complex-valued continuous functions on $X$. The space $X$ is in fact extremally disconnected.

Here goes my question(s). Just as the norm topology of $A$ is captured by the $\sup$ norm of the function algebra over $X$, what is an analogous description of the ultraweak topology on $A$? For instance, if we want to say $f_{\alpha} \rightarrow f$ in the ultraweak topology, how do we phrase such a statement in purely topological terms (in terms of $X$ and its topology)?

Thank you.

Edit: Clarified some aspects to make the question more specific. Looking around mathoverflow brought me to the following two discussions which captures the spirit of my question:
1) [Reference for the Gelfand-Neumark theorem for commutative von Neumann algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23408/reference-for-the-gelfand-neumark-theorem-for-commutative-von-neumann-algebras)
2) [What kind of completion is this?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60328/what-kind-of-completion-is-this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

მამუკა ჯიბლაძე hints that "hyperstonian" is an important definition here.  I have struggled to find a good internet reference, and so am following Section 1 of Chapter III of Takesaki's book.

A *Stonian* space is a compact Hausdorff [Extremally disconnected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space).  A *rare* or [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) set $M$ is such that the closure of $M$ has empty interior.

Let $X$ be a Stonian space and let $C_{\mathbb R}(X)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$.  A (positive, Radon) measure $\mu$ on $X$ is *normal* if whenever $(f_i)$ is an increasing bounded net in $C_{\mathbb R}(X)$ and $f$ is the least upper bound of $\{f_i\}$ in $C_{\mathbb R}(X)$ (which exists as $X$ is Stonian), then
$$ \int_X f \ d\mu = \sup_i \int_X f_i \ d\mu. $$
Alternatively, $\mu$ is normal if $\mu(M)=0$ for all (closed) rare sets $M$.

Finally, $X$ is *hyperstonian* if it admits sufficiently many normal measures: for any non-zero $f\in C_{\mathbb R}(X)$ there is a normal $\mu$ with $\int_X f\ d\mu\not=0$.

For a compact Hausdorff $X$, we have that $C(X)$ is a von Neumann algebra exactly when $X$ is hyperstonian.

Define a real-valued Radon measure to be normal if its positive and negative parts are normal; analogously for complex Radon measures.  Following the proofs through, it follows that the predual of $C(X)$ is exactly the collection of complex normal measures on $X$.

But I wonder if this answers the original question: is this in terms of "$X$ and its topology"?  However, notice that the difference between Stonian and Hyperstonian is very measure theoretic in nature.

Comment: *Alternatively, $\mu$ is normal if $\mu(M)=0$ for all (closed) rare sets $M$*. Is this statement in the sense of an alternative definition of normality or a result?

Comment: @quasinilpotent This is Proposition 1.11 in Takesaki Chapter III

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, Got it. I guess the *if* instead of *if and only if* caused me some confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that a $C^\ast$-algebra is a von Neumann algebra means that it is a dual space (as a Banach space). The ultraweak topology is then what functional analysts call the weak-$\ast$ topology. In the case where it is an $L^\infty$ space then it is the weak topology induced in the natural way by $L^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am curious about a description in terms of the topology of $X$. For an extremally disconnected space $X$, is there an explicit description of the pre-dual of $C(X)$ in terms of $X$?

Comment: @quasinilpotent Not all extremally disconnected spaces are hyperstonean, i. e. have von Neumann $C$. See [an answer on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065401/214353) for an example: the Stone space of the complete Boolean algebra of regular open sets in $\mathbb R$ is extremally disconnected but not hyperstonean.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, looks like I have had the wrong idea the whole time. Thanks for your explanation.